# JQUERY - Mouseout

Tags: jquery, mouseout

I am having problems using .mouseout I am no expert :)

I have a set of images (with ids #image-1,#image-2..) that when hovering a set of < span > with ids #for-image-1, #for-image-2... give opacity to the assigned image:

This is the first part of the script /WORKS FINE/, it removes opacity of all images and adds the opaque class to the  image assigned when hovering the correct < span >

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#secciones span").hover(function() {
    $("#golfball img").removeClass("opaque");

    var imageToShow = $(this).attr("id").replace("for-", "");
    $("#golfball #"+imageToShow).addClass("opaque");

  });
});

</script>
```

This is the other half, and where I´m having the problem, I want the first image that has the id #image-1 to recover opacity on mouse out of any < span >

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#secciones span").mouseout(function() {
    $("#image-1").addClass("opaque");

  });
});

</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The ball should get back to normal on mouseout over PRECIO

Answer (score 1):

Might be a silly question, but is there a reason you use hover in one and mouseout in another?

Also, have you created more than one HTML element with the same ID?  ID's should be unique in your HTML, class tags do not have to be.  This may cause undesirable effects.

The jQuery API page (http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) for mouseover/mouseout shows an example of chaining these two events on the element:

```
$("div.overout").mouseover(function() {
    i += 1;
    $(this).find("span").text( "mouse over x " + i );
  }).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).find("span").text("mouse out ");
  });
```

If I am understanding correctly, this is what you would want to give a shot with.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure i am understanding this correctly, but if you want to get the opacity back maybe change on mouseout

```
 $("#image-1").addClass("opaque");
```

to

```
 $("#image-1").removeClass("opaque");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need IE6-Support? If yes - make your Boss understand that IE6 sucks and everyone using it is not worth being your customer :P (oh if it just were that easy...). But if you don't need this, you do not need javascript at all, a simple CSS will do:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2GXny/

```
<div class="imgContainer">
  <img style="width:100px; height:100px;" src="./test.jpg" alt="some alt" />
  <span>lalalalalaa</span>
  <img style="width:100px; height:100px;" src="./test.jpg" alt="some alt" />
  <span>lalalalalaa</span>
</div>
```

With the associated CSS:

```
.imgContainer span { display: none; }
.imgContainer img:hover + span { display:inline; }
```

Obviously styling is needed to position the spans, etc... Works well across browsers but IE6 - obviously....

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the hover function to call both mouse in and mouse out. Try this.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#secciones span").hover(function() {
       $("#golfball img").removeClass("opaque");

       var imageToShow = $(this).attr("id").replace("for-", "");
       $("#golfball #"+imageToShow).addClass("opaque");

   },
   function(){
       $("#image-1").addClass("opaque");
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The jquery hover function typically takes two arguments: hoverIn and hoverOut. Instead of binding a mouseout event, pass your "make opaque" function to the hover binding.

```
$('#secciones span').hover(
    function() {
        $("#golfball img").removeClass("opaque");

        var imageToShow = $(this).attr("id").replace("for-", "");
        $("#golfball #"+imageToShow).addClass("opaque");

    },
    function() {
        $("#image-1").addClass("opaque");           
    }
);
```

By including a second function, you don't need mouseout as that is already controlled by the hover function.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div id='secciones'>
    <span>
        <div id='golfball'>
            <img src='http://kaczanowscy.pl/tomek/sites/default/files/test_result_green.png'><br />
            <img src='http://www.careercup.com/attributeimage?pid=microsoft-interview-questions'><br />
            <img src='http://img.brothersoft.com/games/flash/icon/m/math-test-3572-1264177735.jpg'>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

Script

```
$(function () {
    $('#golfball img').each(function () {
        $(this).css('opacity', '0.3').bind({
            mouseenter : function () {
                $(this).animate({
                    opacity : 1.0
                });
                //you may add class here
            },
            mouseleave : function () {
                $(this).animate({
                    opacity : 0.5
                });
                // you may remove class here
            }
        });
    });
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jonevar/tZcn9/1/)

---

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @StuperUser I can't be more agree. I will keep in mind for next post. Thanks.